# Portugal representative or Portugal's represntative

Tags: sentence-structure

There is a company in USA (let's call this company "ABU")and a person from Portugal became a manager of the representative of ABU in Portugal.

How is the right way to describe this representative?

Can I say "Portugal representative" in this case? 
Is it better to say "ABU representative in Portugal"

Comment: What do you mean by "representative" here? Is it an overseas branch of the company?

Comment: Yes, it is. (overseas branch of the company)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't normally say *Portugal representative* because you would not use *Portugal* as a modifier, but instead use *Portuguese*:

> Portuguese representative

Then in your case you could say:

> *the* **Portuguese** representative of ABU

or

> *the* **ABU** representative in Portugal
>   **ABU's** representative in Portugal